# PyQt5: pyuic5 - Unknown Qt widget: QKeySequenceEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Built a ui with Qt Designer 5.11.1, and I added a QKeySequenceEdit. Now trying to convert the ui to .py, and receiving the error below.

```
PS C:\dev\app> pyuic5 app.ui > appui.py
Unknown Qt widget: QKeySequenceEdit
```

Here is just a simple ui with the Key Sequence Edit.

app.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QKeySequenceEdit" name="keySequenceEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>150</x>
      <y>380</y>
      <width>113</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: please share yoor .ui

Comment: Test .ui file added.

Comment: @AQuick This is a bug. Please report it on the [pyqt mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt) so that it gets fixed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is a bug, so if a solution is to modify the qtproxies.py that in my case is in `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/uic/Compiler/qtproxies.py` and add a line in:

```
class QtWidgets(ProxyNamespace):
    # ...
    class QCommandLinkButton(QPushButton): pass
    class QKeySequenceEdit(QWidget): pass # add this line

    # Add all remaining classes.
    for _class in _qwidgets:
        if _class not in locals():
            locals()[_class] = type(_class, (QWidget, ), {})
```

It is also recommended that you use `-o` instead of `>` since sometimes it will cause problems in the second

```
pyuic5 app.ui -o appui.py -x
```